# Making Sitecore ignore the call to an API, while manually adding a page to the tracker

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

Sitecore 8.2 U4

I am working on tracking the movement of the user through my registration form. As they move from section to section, I am going to add a page to their tracker so I can see that movement in a Sitecore funnel.

I am making an API call to a controller `/apis/v1/registration/tracksection/{section}`. In that controller I am calling `Tracker.Current?.CurrentPage?.Cancel()` to stop the API url from being tracked by Sitecore. Later in that controller I am calling the code below to insert a page into the tracker. I am basically trying to fake a call to a page the user didn't actually go to. I am doing this so I can track the user's UI experience in a Funnel. A funnel only tracks Sitecore pages, so I have to fake these pages in the tracker.

But the issue is that after I run the code below. The API call goes back into the page history. If I comment out of the code below, the API is removed from page history via the `Tracker.Current?.CurrentPage?.Cancel()` code as expected. Any idea how I can remove the API call and still inject the fake pages? Is there a different way I can add a page to the tracker that might work?

```
var page = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.CreatePage();
page.SetItemProperties(Registration.Constants.Ids.ClubInformation.Guid, "en-us", 1);
page.SetUrl(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Registration.Constants.Ids.ClubInformation).Url());
```

Comment: Which Sitecore version are you using? If it's Sitecore 9, you could use xConnect to create an interaction with required pages.

Comment: @grg This is 8.2 U4.

Answer (score 4):

You have to cancel the page and tell the tracker about it, with

```
Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.AcceptModifications();
```

before you start adding pages to the tracker. If you don’t accept changes, it will just bring the original page back into the tracker.

```
Tracker.Current?.CurrentPage?.Cancel();
Tracker.Current?.Session.Interaction.AcceptModifications(); 

var page = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.CreatePage();
page.SetItemProperties(pageGuid.Guid, "en-us", 1);
page.SetUrl(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(pageGuid).Url());
```